# Can a SMPS transition between 2 unsynchronised AC power sources

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

can a SMPS handle an instantanous transition between the grid AC and the inverter AC? even if the waveforms are unsinchronised?

with a simple 3Pole 2Throw changeover switch

also happy to use a latching relay as this can be automated for aditional functionality

some context for loads, mostly things like lcd computer monitors @ 40W,  sterio amplifier @30W , laptops @ 90W , Desktops @ 100w

i would be concerned though about doing it with the desktop PC, as this is the only sensitive device listed. i'll research whether UPS's synchronise AC waveforms.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need enough input capacitance, and It also depents on the load. You can try to calculate It but I Think it's easier to Just try it out. However I would not reccomend using handswitch, because it May be possible to vary switching time a lot. Instead Relay + latching circuit can be used.

Ac to dc smps works like this:

1. rectyficate Input 50Hz to dc (for 230V mains  it's 325V rectified)
2. switch this Dc with high frequency throught transformer (to transform it to needed voltage)
3. rectyficate high frequency voltage to dc at output.

All of this is done to reduce size and cost of such supply, because components working with higher frequency can be significantly smaller (eg. transformer).

To obtain smooth input dc voltage to swich it into transformer - capacitors are used. They allow converter to work continously even when input voltage pulses 100 times per second (mains). Their main task is to provide enough energy between halves of sine to allow for continous work of smps. BUT in most cases they have much bigger value (for example supply can work in multiplier input mode on 110V and then more capacitance is needed) This leads to the situation, when converter works for a moment, when it is unplugged from mains. You can use this fact to swich input source to smps, and it will not even notice a difference (voltage might start dropping on capacitors, but converter will then extend duty cycle to adjust to it, so if You are fast enough It's possible)

Comment: please could you kindly expand on the input capacitance? i will add some more context about load below , thanks

Answer (score 1):

As a working example, the ATX PSU spec gives a hold-up time of 17ms, which corresponds to one 60Hz cycle. Any other supply you will need to check on this, but it's likely to be similar to ATX.

So an instant electronic switch could work - there will never be a case of a full-cycle dropout regardless of the inverter vs. line phase.

Could a mechanical switch do the same thing? Probably not - the switchover time will be too long.

That said, the way backup UPS units work is they internally convert to DC, which in turn is fed by either the line or battery, then convert back to AC with the inverter. This ensures a smooth transition between the two power sources. If you are really concerned about the switchover case you should be thinking about a design like this.

Comment: "Could a mechanical switch do the same thing?" I believe it definitely can. Only an "online" UPS design provides smooth transition by double conversion. A much cheaper "offline/standby" UPS indeed uses a mechanical relay to switch, and there will be a power interruption of many milliseconds before the backup power is on, but in practice, the ATX hold-up time is enough for a smooth transition.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are referring to a standard mains AC to DC SMPS, then changing the source should have no affect on the supply because it rectifies and filters the mains supply to DC before doing any regulation.

This is how moderns PSUs can support 50/60/400Hz supplies and different voltage standards. By using a DC supply, they can then chop the signal at its own much higher frequency (kHz to MHz), completely asynchronous to the AC mains frequency, before feeding through a small transformer to drop the voltage and then rectifying again.